# how can make relation between 2 table in 2 database in one instance without Link server

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I want to connect with *[relationships](/questions/tagged/relationships)* between 2 tables in 2 databases without link server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: When you say two different databases i'm guessing you mean on two separate servers otherwise just look at 'The beginner''s answer on this.

You can use `FROM OPENDATASOURCE` but Microsoft doesn't recommended this as the security details are in the connection string, a Linked Server is the best way to go about it.

The Microsoft Docs is [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/opendatasource-transact-sql), and a handy post is [HERE](http://www.sqlserver.info/syntax/connect-to-remote-database-without-a-linked-server/).

The syntax will look something like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Connection String')."DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."TABLE" T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 on T1.Id = T2.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM [FIRST_DB].[dbo].[FIRST_Table] tab1
    INNER JOIN [SECOND_DB].[dbo].[SECOND_Table] tab2
        ON tab1.[COMMON COLUMN]= tab2.[COMMON COLUMN]
```